# Results about "morphisms" of "semi"-exact sequences in a regular category

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

I'm looking for any kind of references for generally useful results about commutative diagrams of the following kind (possibly with more rows):

[image]

where $(R_1,R_2)$ and $(S_1,S_2)$ are congruences and we usually have at least one of the following for each fork (row):

- the congruence is the kernel pair of the right arrow
- the right arrow is a coequalizer of the congruence

If both apply, I would call this an exact fork (to not confuse it with exact sequences in the homological sense). Accordingly there should be names for forks where one of the above apply (left exact, right exact perhaps?).

It says "regular category" in the title and that is my main concern, but it can be more general too.

I know of Chapter IV of "Categorical Foundations - Special Topics in Order, Topology, Algebra, and Sheaf Theory" where e.g. the so called Barr-Kock theorem is stated and proved. But I wonder whether there are other useful references with more results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article "[The denormalized $3\times 3$ lemma](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404902001433)" by Dominique Bourn proves a version of the $3\times 3$ lemma for such "exact sequences" in regular Mal'tsev categories, though some partial results still hold without the Mal'tsev assumption. It uses your "left/right exact" terminology. The result also holds for Goursat categories : see [this article](http://maths.mq.edu.au/~slack/papers/3by3.html) and
[these slides](http://ct2010.disi.unige.it/slides/Rodelo_CT2010.pdf) from CT2010 for more information.

Comment: The article is cited in the book you mentioned in your question, so maybe you were aware of it...

Comment: Well, perhaps I should have checked the references in that book first... - it's not much (for the non-Mal'cev case), but it's a start.